# Can't save a shelf set because of something missing

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I was trying to save a shelf set this afternoon on a project I created today. I got an error message that reads:

Team Foundation Error

> D:\Src\MiniCoreWebAPI\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.5.2.1\lib\net451\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll:
>   Could not find a part of the path

I've looked and sure enough, there's no D:\Src\MiniCoreWebAPI\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.5.2.1 nor anything that would be under it. But I'm not sure what to do about it. This was created by the VS 2017 scaffolding. So, how do I get to save the shelf set, if this is preventing me from doing so.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by Daniel's suggestion? any update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the file from your pending changes.

Better yet, create a standard `.tfignore` file that excludes the packages folder, as NuGet packages should not be put into source control.